# How to Associate Static vbs file to Test in UFT and save it

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft, alm

I've 200 UFT (14) tests in ALM for which i need to associate 10 function libraries each, save the test back to ALM (11.53) and check in the Test in Test Plan.

**Is there any way to do this ?**

I know that there are 4 ways to associate vbs files to a Test.

1) By using ‘File > Settings > Resources > Associate Function Library’ option in QTP.

2) By using Automation Object Model (AOM).

3) By using ExecuteFile method.

4) using LoadFunctionLibrary method.

```
    In that Method - 3, 4 --> has association only in Runtime (taking long time to start 
the execution ~ 2 mins per execution)

    Method - 2 --> needs to trigger execution from local. I tried this by using the below 
code but the Test is not getting saved back to ALM.

    Method - 1 --> Better approach, but can't do it manually for all 200 tests
```

Below is the code

```
Set objCon = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.tdconnection")
objCon.InitConnectionEx URL
objCon.Login User, Pass
objCon.Connect Domain, Project

gstrRelativePath = "[ALM] Subject\Automation Development\Training"

Set gobjQtpApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
gobjQtpApp.Open gstrRelativePath & "\Test"  

Set objQtpSettings = gobjQtpApp.Test.Settings
Set objQtpLibraries = objQtpSettings.Resources.Libraries
objQtpLibraries.RemoveAll
objQtpLibraries.Add "Support Libraries\" & objFile.Name
gobjQtpApp.Test.Save
```

Comment: Get all the script names along with their path and run your code in loop on it.